# How to make a parse tree from Follow() set in LL parsing?

Tags: parsing, grammar, ll-grammar, parse-tree

I was given the question for test:
Show the parse tree of a string proving that b is in the follow of T.

```
S=> ET
T=>bSc | d
E=>aTE| ε
```

I solved the First set :

```
First(S)=>First(E)=>{a} U First(T)=> {a,b,d}
First(T)=>{b,d}
First(E)=>{a,ε}
```

And the Follow set :

```
Follow(S)=>{$,c}
Follow(T)=>Follow(S) U First(E)=> {$,c} U First(E)=>{$,c,a}
Follow(E)=>First(T) U Follow(E)=>{b,d}
```

Where I am going wrong ?﻿

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

> Follow(T) ⇒ Follow(S) ∪ First(E)

But ε is in First(E), so that should be:

> Follow(T) ⇒ Follow(S) ∪ First(E) ∪ Follow(E)